# Using Kafka Connect in distributed mode, where are internal topics supposed to exist

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As a follow up to my previous question here [Attempting to run Kafka Connect in distributed mode locally, problem with internal topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275230/attempting-to-run-kafka-connect-in-distributed-mode-locally-problem-with-intern), I have started to figure out what might really be going on (I'm learning Kafka as I go).

Kafka Connect, one way or another, requires three internal topics: config, offset, and status. Are these topics supposed to exist in the Kafka cluster where I am consuming data from? For context, what I'm doing is someone else has a Kafka cluster set up that has topics (messages?) for me to consume. I spin up a Kafka Connect cluster on my local machine (to test) and this local instance (we'll call it that going forward) then connects to the remote Kafka cluster (we'll call it the remote cluster) by way of me typing in the bootstrap servers, some callback handler classes, and a connect.jaas file.

Do these three topics need to already exist on the **remote cluster**? Here I have been trying to create them on my own broker on my local instance, but through continued research, I'm seeing maybe these three internal topics need to be on the remote cluster (where I'm getting my data from). Does the owner of the remote Kafka cluster need to create these three topics for me? Where would they create them exactly? What if their cluster is not a Kafka Connect cluster specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topics need to be created on the cluster defined by `bootstrap.servers` in the Connect worker properties. This can be local or remote, depending on what data you actually want the connector tasks to send/receive. Individual connect tasks cannot override what brokers are being used (not possible to use a source connector to write to multiple Kafka clusters, for example)

Latest versions of Kafka Connect will automatically create those internal topics, if it is authorized to do so. Otherwise, yes, they'll need to be created using `kafka-topics --create` with appropriate partition counts and replication factors.

If your data exists in a remote Kafka cluster, the only reason to run a local instance is if you want to use MirrorMaker, for example.

> What if their cluster is not a Kafka Connect cluster specifically?

Unclear what this means. Kafka Connect is a client just like a Kafka Streams app or normal producer or consumer. It doesn't store topics itself.